# jQuery .each() with multiple selectors - skip, then .empty() elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, each

I'd like to remove all matching elements, but skip the first instance of each match:

```
// Works as expected: removes all but first instance of .a
jQuery ('.a', '#scope')
    .each ( function (i) { 
        if (i > 0) jQuery (this).empty();
    });

// Expected: removal of all but first instance of .a and .b
// Result: removal of *all* instances .a and .b
jQuery ('.a, .b', '#scope')
    .each ( function (i) { 
        if (i > 1) jQuery (this).empty();
    });

<div id="scope">

    <!-- Want to keep the first instance of .a and .b -->

    <div class="a">[bla]</div>
    <div class="b">[bla]</div>

    <!-- Want to remove all the others -->

    <div class="a">[bla]</div>
    <div class="b">[bla]</div>

    <div class="a">[bla]</div>
    <div class="b">[bla]</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

- Using `jQuery()` rather than `$()` because of conflict with 'legacy' code
- Using `.empty()` because `.a` contains JS I'd like to disable
- Stuck with jQuery 1.2.3

Thanks you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$('.a:gt(0), .b:gt(0)').remove();
```

I'm not sure if combining them into one selector is possible with the `:gt()`, it may change the scope and remove all of them after the first `.a`.

Comment: It _is_ possible to use `:gt()` with a combined selector:


`jQuery ('.a:gt(0), .b:gt(0)').empty()` works well.

Are you able to suggest why my approach wasn't working?

Thank you!

Comment: Oh no, you're right I tried that and yours is working fine as well. **Edited my answer**.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your HTML is incorrect.  I modified it to the following:

```
<div id="scope">

    <!-- Want to keep the first instance of .a and .b -->

    <div class="a">[bla]</div>
    <div class="b">[bla]</div>

    <!-- Want to remove all the others -->

    <div class="a">[bla]</div>
    <div class="b">[bla]</div>

    <div class="a">[bla]</div>
    <div class="b">[bla]</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Then this seemed to work:

```
jQuery('div#scope div.a').not(':first').empty();
jQuery('div#scope div.b').not(':first').empty();
```

Comment: HTML typo was only in my simplified example.

Thanks for your suggestion!